# Extract word terms from sentence between the symbol '<>' and the nested case '<<>>'

Tags: python, regex

Named Entity Recognition news dataset (text)

Here is a sample:

```
<LOC Qatar> and <LOC Japan>, who met in the <EVENT <S Asian> <E Cup>> final in <DATE February>, are in third place in their groups.
```

I'm trying to extract the entities which are between <>, the problem in the nested labels and the output is:

```
['<LOC Qatar>',
 '<LOC Japan>',
 '<EVENT <S Asian>',
 '<E Cup>',
 '<DATE February>']
```

It is wrong because "EVENT S Asian", "E Cup" should be one string not two.

I'v tried regEx but it doesn't work well.

```
import re
s = """<LOC Qatar> and <LOC Japan>, 
who met in the <EVENT <S Asian> <E Cup>> final in <DATE February>, are in third place in their groups."""
re.findall('\<.*?\>',s)
```

Actual results:

```
['<LOC Qatar>',
 '<LOC Japan>',
 '<EVENT <S Asian>',
 '<E Cup>',
 '<DATE February>']
```

Expected results:

```
['<LOC Qatar>',
 '<LOC Japan>',
 '<EVENT <S Asian> <E Cup>>',
 '<DATE February>']
```

Comment: That is true the concept is almost the same, I was trying to implement in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to apply **recursive** pattern as mentioned in comments. The **`regex`** module give you opportunity (not the `re` module).

Here the code:

```
# Import module
import regex as reg

# Your string
s = """<LOC Qatar> and <LOC Japan>, 
who met in the < EVENT < S Asian > < E Cup >> final in < DATE February > , are in third place in their groups. """

# Match pattern
my_list = reg.findall("<((?:[^<>]|(?R))*)>", s)
print(my_list)
# ['LOC Qatar', 'LOC Japan', ' EVENT < S Asian > < E Cup >', ' DATE February ']
```

if you really want the words surrounded by `<>`, you can add them:

```
my_list = ['<' + elt + '>' for elt in my_list]
print(my_list)
# ['<LOC Qatar>', '<LOC Japan>', '< EVENT < S Asian > < E Cup >>', '< DATE February >']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right. I was trying to implement ```(\<([^<>]|\<?R\>)*\>)```  using ```re```